# Xpath select items except last item wth contain syntax

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I want to select the following html items (action,comedy) but except the last one (tags).

To select all my follow code is working:

```
//*[@id="video-tags"]//a[contains(@href,'tags')]
```

But to select except the last one (tags), it won't work with my follow code:

```
//*[@id="video-tags"]//a[contains(@href,'tags') not(position() > last() -1)]
```

The html

```
<ul id="video-tags">
        <li>Uploader: </li>
        <li class="profile_name"><a href="/profiles/wilco">wilco</a></li>
        <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
        <li><a href="/tags/action">action</a>, </li>
        <li><a href="/tags/comedy">comedy</a>, </li>
        <li>more <a href="/tags/"><strong>tags</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Nick

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aside from the syntax error - you need an `and`, i.e. `contains(@href,'tags') and not(position()...)` - you're tripping up on a subtlety of how `//` is defined.

The XPath `//a[position() < last()]` will *not* give you every `a` except the last one, it will give you every `a` that is not the last `a` inside its respective parent element.  Since each `li` contains at most one `a`, *every* `a` is the last `a` in its respective parent, so this test will match nothing at all.

You can achieve what you want by wrapping most of the expression in parentheses and putting the `position` check in a separate predicate

```
(//*[@id="video-tags"]//a[contains(@href,'tags')])[position() < last()]
```

The parentheses cause the final predicate to apply to the node set selected by the expression as a whole, rather than just to the `a` location step, i.e. it will first find all the `a` elements whose `href` contains "tags", then return all but the last of these selected elements in document order.

---

Technical explanation - the definition of `//` in XPath is that it is a shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` (including the slashes), which is a location step that gives you this node and all its descendant nodes.  So `//a` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::a`, and `//a[something]` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::a[something]` - the predicate applies to the `child::` step, not the `descendant-or-self::` one.  If you want to apply a predicate to the descendant search then you should use the `descendant::` axis explicitly - `/descendant::a[something]`.

Comment: Great explanation as usual!

Comment: Really helpful! Lot of things I learned today from you.. :) *+1*.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(//ul[@id="video-tags"]//a[contains(@href,'tags')]/text())
```

Comment: That would select the text node children of the `a` elements rather than the `a` elements themselves.